# how to deploy MVC3 WebApp to windows Azure

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, azure

How is it possible to deploy MVC3 web roles to windows Azure? Most of the tutorials seems done on deploying ASP.NET web roles than the MVC3 one.

can any one give me a link/hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Way back in the old days, MVC3 wasn't supported out-of-the-box because the appropriate DLLs needed to be manually added by you (or installed as a startup task). These days, the MVC dll's are all there using the MVC3 template, so there's no difference in what you'd need to do, between asp.net and asp.net mvc deployment. The basic Web Roles and Worker roles are just Windows 2008 Server VMs, and the deployment process is the same. The most important part, when starting out, is making sure your connection strings to storage point to "real" storage and not dev storage (such as your diagnostics connection string). Also, session state defaults to using SQLExpress, which isn't running in Windows Azure, so you'll need to either use a SQL Azure database (plus proper connection string) in web.config, or change session state to use Cache (again, a web.config change).

Comment: @David..Thank you for the hint really. well currently want to work with the emulator and my storage to be tables. Do I need to set the connection string at web.config?  it seems that I cant get a fine tutorial on that. At least a sample with CRUD operations. tnx again!

Comment: okie..Now it seems that I have got a clue. The easiest way perhaps is to migrate normal Asp.net mvc3 web apps. there I can add a cloud solution and few .dlls(service runtime,diagnostics)....http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jnak/archive/2010/02/08/migrating-an-existing-asp-net-app-to-run-on-windows-azure.aspx

Comment: Are you sure the MVC dlls are included in the VMs by default?  I thought the new templates were just better at adding setting them to be copied without you having to do anything?  I can't find any MVC dlls in this list: http://gacviewer.cloudapp.net/Default.aspx

Comment: @knightpfhor You're correct - I was going for the ultra-simple answer, and was trying to convey the fact that you don't need to go anything like you used to need to, in order to get the mvc assemblies set up (such as grabbing them yourself and setting copy-local, or setting up a startup task to install mvc via webPI). I'll clarify in the answer.